# How to format nodes in a TreeView control bold (Access 2013)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a treeview control in Access 2013 where I want to change the Top level nodes to be bold.  I am using an ActiveX Control: Microsoft TreeView Control 6.0 (SP4).

I populate the tree using

```
'VBA 

Set newNode = Me.myTree.Nodes.Add(Text:=nodeText, Key:=parentKey)
With 
  newNode .ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0) 
End With.
```

I want to somehow change the .NodeFont node property so that the text is bold.

The solutions I could find online, such as [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenode.nodefont?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TreeNode_NodeFont), says to use something like:

```
 myTreeView.SelectedNode.NodeFont = new Font("Arial", FontStyle.Bold);
```

This causes loading the tree to fail with a syntax error highlighting that line, but no other useful information. I have tried playing with it and replicating solutions that seemed to work for others, but with no luck.

I know that my selection of the node is correct, because I am able to change some of the node properties such as the Tag or the ForeColor.

Why isn't `new Font()` working? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Treeview OCX control, font formatting (including bold) is applied directly to the node.

So:

```
  Set newNode = Me.myTree.Nodes.Add(Text:=nodeText, Key:=parentKey)
  With newNode 
    .ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0) 
    .Bold = True
  End With
```

Note: The link and code metioned in the question is for the .NET Framework, not VBA, which is why `New Font()` doesn't (and cannot) work. Generally, in VBA it's not possible to use the `New` keyword; usually, the method `Add` is used. So when working in VBA, if code using `New` is encountered, be very careful that it's applicable to VBA. (The only time `New` can be used in VBA is for a new instance of an application, for example `Set wdApp = New Word.Application` when coding in Excel.)